# Load projects based on build configuration in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, buildconfiguration

I've couple of different projects in my solution(around 70). A couple of dll projects, test projects, service projects and a web project. And I've multiple build configurations(test, debug etc). Not all projects are part of every build configuration.

I was wondering whether there is any way I can configure visual studio to load only projects that are part of the build configuration.

Comment: I have the very same question. Did you find an answer?